# Como implementar infinite scrolling en recyclerview

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

tengo un recycler y dentro de ese recycler se muestran cardviews con info traida desde una API REST y quisiera implementar esta caracteristica en mi aplicacion pero no se como hacerlo, he visto varios ejemplos en linea pero no logro captar que es lo que va en el adapter y que es lo que va en el main, si pudieran guiarme o mostrarme un ejemplo facil lo agradeceria mucho

**Adapter**

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private ArrayList<Business> basicsList;

    Bitmap bitmap;
    private Context mContext;
    int idb;
    private Activity activity;
    private int layoutMolde;


    public SearchAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Business> list, int layout ) {

        this.activity = activity;
        this.basicsList = list;
        layoutMolde = layout;
    }

    @Override
    public SearchAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_row, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // holder.mTitle.setText(premiumsList.get(position));
        holder.mTitle.setText(basicsList.get(position).getName());

        //holder.mImg.setImageURI(Uri.parse(premiumsList.get(position).getLogo_url_string()));
        idb = basicsList.get(position).getId();

        if (basicsList.get(position).getRating()==null){
            holder.txtsearch.setText(0);

        }else {
            holder.txtsearch.setText(basicsList.get(position).getRating());
        }


        if(basicsList.get(position).getLogo_url_string()!=null){
            Glide.with(activity).load(basicsList.get(position).getLogo_url_string()).into(holder.mImg);
            Log.d("",String.valueOf(basicsList.get(position).getIcon_default()));
        }
        else{
            Glide.with(activity).load(basicsList.get(position).getIcon_default()).into(holder.mImg);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return basicsList.size();
    }



    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView mTitle;
        public ImageView mImg;
        public ImageView logo;
        public RatingBar rating_basic;
        public TextView txtsearch;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nom_search);
            mImg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_search);

            txtsearch=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtsearch_rating);
            rating_basic=(RatingBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating_search);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(), BusinessPremium.class);
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    idb = basicsList.get(position).getId();
                    in.putExtra("no", idb);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(in);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment**

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment
{
    private ArrayList<Business> arrayBusiness,arrayBasics;

    private Gson gson;

    private static final Type BUSINESS_TYPE = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Business>>() {}.getType();
    private TextView textView;

    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLowerLayoutManager;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_activity, container, false);
        textView = (TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) android.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        if (!internetConnectionCheck(SearchFragment.this.getActivity()))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error de Conexión", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        new PlifRequestBase(getActivity())
        {
            @Override

            public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
            {

                JsonObject data, pagination_details = null, businesses, cover_premium, cv, iurl;

                JsonArray premiums, basics;
                String url_img;

                if (response.get("pagination") == null)
                {

                    data =  response;
                }else {
                    pagination_details = response.get("pagination").getAsJsonObject();
                    data = response.get("data").getAsJsonObject();

                    businesses = data.get("businesses").getAsJsonObject();
                    premiums = businesses.get("premiums").getAsJsonArray();

                    //images_premiums=data.get("category_image").getAsJsonObject();

                    basics = businesses.get("basics").getAsJsonArray();

                    gson = new Gson();
                    arrayBusiness = new ArrayList<Business>();
                    arrayBasics= new ArrayList<Business>();

                    arrayBusiness = gson.fromJson(premiums, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                    arrayBasics=gson.fromJson(basics, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                    Log.d("size", String.valueOf(arrayBusiness.size()));
                    //Log.d("", String.valueOf(images_premiums));
                        if (getActivity() == null)
                        return response;
                    SearchFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) SearchFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.high_recycler_view);
                            SearchAdapter adapter = new SearchAdapter(getActivity(), arrayBusiness, R.layout.search_low_layout);
                            recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                            mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(SearchFragment.this.getActivity(),2);
                            recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                            recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

                            for (int i = 0; i < arrayBusiness.size(); i++)
                            {
                                Log.d("Imprime", arrayBusiness.get(i).getName());
                            }

                            GifTextView loading = (GifTextView)SearchFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingSearch);
                            TextView loadingText = (TextView)SearchFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingTextSearch);
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });

                }
                if (pagination_details.isJsonNull())
                {
                    Log.d("Paginacion", pagination_details.toString());
                }
                return data;
            }
            @Override
            public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onHttpUnprocessableEntity(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                this.cancel(true);
                final String error = response.get("errors").toString();
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }.execute("businesses/search", "GET");
        return android;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        final MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
        //final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setQueryHint(getText(R.string.search));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(final String query)
            {
                //Toast.makeText(SearchFragment.this.getActivity(), R.string.buscado, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                searchView.setQuery("", false);
                searchView.setIconified(true);
                new PlifRequestBase(getActivity()){
                    @Override
                    public JsonObject onHttpOk(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
                    {
                        JsonObject data, pagination_details = null, businesses, cover_premium, cv, iurl;
                        JsonArray premiums, basics;
                        if (response.get("pagination") == null)
                        {
                            data =  response;
                        }else {
                            pagination_details = response.get("pagination").getAsJsonObject();
                            data = response.get("data").getAsJsonObject();

                            businesses = data.get("businesses").getAsJsonObject();
                            premiums = businesses.get("premiums").getAsJsonArray();
                            basics = businesses.get("basics").getAsJsonArray();

                            gson = new Gson();
                            arrayBusiness = new ArrayList<Business>();
                            arrayBasics= new ArrayList<Business>();

                            arrayBusiness = gson.fromJson(premiums, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                            arrayBasics=gson.fromJson(basics, BUSINESS_TYPE);
                            Log.d("size", String.valueOf(arrayBusiness.size()));
                            //Log.d("", String.valueOf(images_premiums));

                            SearchFragment.this.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {

                                    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) SearchFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.high_recycler_view);
                                    RecyclerView recyclerbasics=(RecyclerView) SearchFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.lower_recycler_view);

                                    SearchHorizontalAdapter adapter = new SearchHorizontalAdapter(getActivity(), arrayBusiness, R.layout.search_high_layout);
                                    SearchVerticalAdapter adapterbasics=new SearchVerticalAdapter(getActivity(),arrayBasics,R.layout.search_low_layout);

                                    recyclerbasics.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
                                    recycler.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

                                    mLowerLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(SearchFragment.this.getActivity(),2);
                                    recyclerbasics.setLayoutManager(mLowerLayoutManager);
                                    recyclerbasics.setAdapter(adapterbasics);

                                    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(SearchFragment.this.getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                                    recycler.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
                                    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);

                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBusiness.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("Imprime", arrayBusiness.get(i).getName());
                                    }
                                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayBasics.size(); i++)
                                    {
                                        Log.d("Imprime", arrayBasics.get(i).getName());
                                    }
                                    GifTextView loading = (GifTextView)SearchFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingSearch);
                                    TextView loadingText = (TextView)SearchFragment.this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.loadingTextSearch);
                                    loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    loadingText.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        if (pagination_details.isJsonNull()){
                            Log.d("Paginacion", pagination_details.toString());
                        }
                        return data;
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onHttpCreate(JsonObject response) throws JSONException
                    {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onHttpUnprocessableEntity(JsonObject response) throws JSONException {
                        this.cancel(true);
                        final String error = response.get("errors").toString();
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }.execute("businesses/search", "GET", "q", "\'"+query+"\'");

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                textView.setText(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });

        View searchPlate = (View) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
        searchPlate.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.textfield_custom);

        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                action(R.string.action_settings);
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private void action(int resid) {
        Toast.makeText(this.getActivity(), getText(resid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    public static boolean internetConnectionCheck(Activity CurrentActivity) {
        Boolean Connected = false;
        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) CurrentActivity.getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null) {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null) for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    Log.e("My Network is: ", "Connected");
                    Connected = true;
                } else {}
        } else {
            Log.e("My Network is: ", "Not Connected");

            Toast.makeText(CurrentActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                    "Please Check Your internet connection",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Connected = false;

        }
        return Connected;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede conseguir de diferentes formas, a continuación te mostraré como lo he conseguido yo.

**En tu xml de layout de Activity o Fragment vamos a añadirle un SwipeToRefreshLayout para poder refrescar los datos:**

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp" />


        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />



    </RelativeLayout>
```

**Declarar las siguientes variables en tu Fragment o Activity:**

```
private final int VISIBLE_THRESHOLD = 5; // Numero de celdas restantes antes de realizar una nueva petición
private int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount, previousTotal = 0;
private boolean loading = false;

private int offset = 0; //Numero de items cargados
private int limit = 15; //Numero de items por petición

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private MySuperAdapter mAdapter;
```

**En tu metodo onCreate() o onCreateView():**

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

adapter = new MySuperAdapter(context);//Con los params que necesitemos

mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {


            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {

                    offset = 0;
                     obtenerItemsDelServidor(url,limit,offset,true);

            }

        });

        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
                firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

                if (loading) {
                    if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {

                        previousTotal = totalItemCount;
                    }
                }
                if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount) <= (firstVisibleItem + VISIBLE_THRESHOLD)) {


                    // Hemos llegado al final
                    if(adapter.getItemCount()>1) {
                        offset = offset + limit;
                         obtenerItemsDelServidor(url,limit,offset,false);
                    }

                }
            }
        });

// Obtiene datos y actualiza adapter
obtenerItemsDelServidor(url,limit,offset,true);
```

**A continuación debemos crear la función para consultar nuestra fuente de datos:**

```
public void obtenerItemsDelServidor(String url, int limit, int offset,boolean peticionInicial){

//Antes de realizar petición (onPreExecute si utilizamos AsynkTask)

 if (!peticionInicial) {
        loading = true;
        adapter.addItem(null);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  //realizamos petición en background (doInBackground si utilizamos AsynkTask)
  JSONArray responseArray = obtenerJSONServidor(url,params);


  //Recibimos respuesta JSON (onPostExecute si utilizamos AsynkTask)

  if (isPullToRefresh) {
    adapter.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }

  if (!peticionInicial) {
      adapter.removeItem(adapter.getItemCount() - 1);
      loading = false;
   }

  for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {

    JSONObject object = responseArray.getJSONObject(i);
    ListItem item = new ListItem();

    item.setUserName(object.optString("username",""));

    adapter.addItem(item);

  }

  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

  if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
  }

}
```

**Finalmente nos queda configurar nuestro adapter.**

```
public class MySuperAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>{

ArrayList<ListItem> list;
Context context;


private final int VIEW_NORMAL = 0;
private final int VIEW_PROGRESS = 1;

String username;

public MySuperAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {


    RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
    View view;

    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_PROGRESS:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_loadmore, parent, false);
            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(view);
            break;

        case VIEW_NORMAL:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card, parent, false);
            vh = new NormalViewHolder(view);
            break;

    }


    return vh;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ListItem currentItem = list.get(position);

    if (holder instanceof NormalViewHolder) { 



    }  else {
        ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}



public class NormalViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView userName;

    public NormalViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        userName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);

    }

}


public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ProgressBar progressBar;

    public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
}


public void clear() {

    list.clear();

}

public void addItem(ListItem item) {

    list.add(item);
}

public void addItemAtPosition(ListItem item, int position) {

    list.add(position, item);
}

public void removeItem(int position) {

    list.remove(position);

}

public ListItem getItemAtPosition(int position) {

    return list.get(position);

}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        if (list.get(position) != null) {
            return VIEW_NORMAL;
        } else {
            return VIEW_PROGRESS;
        }

}

}
```

**Puntos clave:**

- Antes de empezar una petición que no sea la inicial añadimos una
  celda de progresso en la última posición del array del adapter y
  actualizamos con notifyDataSetChanged(). Cuando la petición ha
  termindo eliminamos la vista de progreso, añadimos los items que nos
  devuelve la petición y volvemos a actualizar con
  notifyDataSetChanged().
- El evento que dispara las peticiones según la posición del scroll en
  la que nos encontremos es el `mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new
  RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()`

Comment: Perdon por contestar hasta ahorita, no habia tenido oportunidad de checar esto y sigo con el problema hasta ahorita la parte que no entiendo del codigo que me proporcionaste es la de obtener items del servidor, haz de cuenta yo hago 1 peticion inicial donde me trae 10 items en cardviews con un Request base y le digo execute("business/premiums" "GET) necesito que cuando llegue hacia abajo hacer otra donde sea("business/premiums?offset=2" "GET") ahorita lo que tengo es que carga los primeros 10 pero luego me reemplaza esos 10 por otros 10 en vez de agregarlos no se si pudieras ayudarme?

Comment: Esto es debido a que cuando recibes los nuevos items NO los añades a la lista de objetos del adapter sino que de alguna manera borras su contenido actual y lo sustituyes. 

Si tienes la primera petición recién hecha deberías tener un array de objetos con un tamaño de 10 en tu adapter. Una vez obtenidos los siguientes 10 lo que tienes que hacer es recorrerlos con un bucle y por cada iteración hacer un adapter.add(item). 

Una vez hayas añadido los 10 tienes que actualizar tu adapter con adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). En ningún caso hagas un adapter.clear() o adapter = new MySuperAdapter();